# How to replace default debian 5 flash installation?

Tags: debian, firefox, flash

How do I replace the default debian 5 flash installation with the adobe version?

I enabled contrib and non-free repositories in the sources.list file.
And installed flashplugin-nonfree.

Logged out and back in, firefox still uses the default one.

I tried removing swfdec-* but that asks for gnome to be removed as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `update-flashplugin --install` and see what the output is.

Also, look into /usr/lib/iceweasel/plugins and perhaps you can manually remove something if all else fails.

What's in about:plugins ?

Answer (score 1):

`update-alternatives --config flash-mozilla.so` will allow you to select which Flash plugin is used.